# Probability of Vigenere cipher

Tags: vigenere

I am trying to figure out this quiz question on a course I am doing but keep getting it wrong.

> Consider the Vigenere cipher over the lowercase English alphabet,
>   where the key can have length 1 or length 2, each with 50%
>   probability. Say the distribution over plaintexts is Pr[M='aa'] = 0.4
>   and Pr[M='ab'] = 0.6. What is Pr[C='bb']? Express your answer to 4
>   decimal places with a leading 0, i.e., if your answer was 1/2 then you
>   would enter 0.5000 (without a trailing period).

The way I reasoned was as follows:
Probability P1 where m=aa and key is of size 1 = 1/26 * 0.4
Probability P2 where m=aa and key is of size 2 = 1/26*1/26*0.4
Probability P3 where m=ab and key is of size 1 = 0
Probability P4 where m=ab and key is of size 2 = 1/26*1/26*0.6

The answer (I thought) was P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 = 0.0169

This is apparently wrong. Can anyone guide me, please?

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply with 0.6 for P4?

Comment: Your answer seems correct, have you tried a truncated number instead of rounded? That would be 0.0168

Comment: sorry copied it wrongly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume the Vigenere cipher is defined to encrypt per $c_i\gets m_i\boxplus k_{(i\bmod l)}$ where $c_i$ is a ciphertext letter, $m_i$ is a plaintext letter, $k_i$ is a key letter, $l$ is the length of the key, $\boxplus$ is the [Vigenere table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#/media/File:Vigen%C3%A8re_square_shading.svg) of dimension 26×26. I'll note $\hat k_i=k_{(i\bmod l)}$.

It is assumed
$$\begin{array}{rlcrl}
\Pr[l=1]&=\frac1 2&\quad&\Pr[l=2]&=\frac1 2\\
\Pr[m_0=\mathtt a\;\wedge\;m_1=\mathtt a]&=\frac2 5&\quad&\Pr[m_0=\mathtt a\;\wedge\;m_1=\mathtt b]&=\frac3 5
\end{array}$$
It is asked $p=\Pr[c_0=\mathtt b\;\wedge\;c_1=\mathtt b]$. That is
$$p=\frac2 5\Pr[\hat k_0=\mathtt b\;\wedge\;\hat k_1=\mathtt b]+\frac3 5\Pr[\hat k_0=\mathtt b\;\wedge\;\hat k_1=\mathtt a]$$

Unfortunately, the problem statement is unclear about the distribution of key. We can reasonably assume that each of the possible $k_0$ has probability $\frac1 {26}$, but what about $k_1$ when $l=2$? It is reasonable to assume one of

1. Each of the possible $k_1$ has probability $\frac1{26}$. That yields
   $$p=\frac2 5\left(\frac1 2\frac1{26}+\frac1 2\frac1{26}\frac1{26}\right)+\frac3 5\left(0+\frac1 2\frac1{26}\frac1{26}\right)=\frac{57}{6760}\approx0.0084$$
   (rounding to the nearest, that is down)
2. Each of the possible $k_1\ne k_0$ has probability $\frac1{25}$. That yields
   $$p=\frac2 5\left(\frac1 2\frac1{26}+0\right)+\frac3 5\left(0+\frac1 2\frac1{26}\frac1{25}\right)=\frac{53}{6500}\approx0.0082$$
   (rounding to the nearest, that is up)

Note: Bet on 1 to maximize the probability of scoring a correct answer, even though 2 is the less unsafe cryptographically.

---

The question's attempted resolution has reading 1, but each of the probability that it sums is missing the multiplication by the probability that $l$ has the value considered.

Comment: Thank you! You are currently my favourite person! I completely forgot the 1/2 probability of length 1 or length 2